# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10e360420) to 'MainApp.detailViewController'

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have two view controller, they are embedded in a NavigationController. The first view controller contains a tableview (populated with a list of strings). I have one more viewcontroller (which I have called detailViewController) which has to appear when tapped in a row of the table. It should display some details about the selected row, I called this "id" in the code below. I have to pass data between these two view controllers when I perform a segue. So first I need the following function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    id = listOfIds[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}
```

Now before we perform the segue, I call the prepare for segue function

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let detailview = segue.destination as! detailViewController
    detailview.id = id
}
```

When I run the application, I get the error

```
 Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10e360420) to 'MainApp.detailViewController'
```

This part of the code is inside bigger application which I am working on. So I made a different small app where I tried to do the same thing, and there it worked like a charm. I do not see how it is not working in this case. What could be the cause so I can debug it?

Comment: What do you think the error message might mean?

Comment: @Fogmeister segue.destination is of type UINavigationController which, according to the error, can not be cast to detailViewController type?

Comment: @Fogmeister I dont understand why it fails here, whereas in a test app it works.

Comment: What does the segue point to I. The storyboard?

Comment: @Fogmeister I control drag from top (the yellow circle with square inside it) of the viewcontroller (which contains the list) to the detailViewController and use "show". This is all inside Storyboard

Comment: @Fogmeister Xcode also gives the error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" which is placed right after the line "let detailview = segue.destination as! ..."